# Simple JS app based on MVC pattern

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I need to implement MVC pattern, by implementing Model and Controller, in order to following code make sense.

```
var Student = new Model({
name: 'John',
age: 22,
year: 5,
examsTaken: 2,
takeExam: function(){
    this.examsTaken++;
    this.changed = true;
}
});

var StudentController = new Controller({
model: Student,
elementId: 'student-container',
render: function(){
    return '<span>' + this.model.name + 
'</span><button id="student-exams-button">Increase exams taken</button>';
},
clickHandlers: {
    '#student-exams-button': 'updateExams'
},
updateExams: function(){
    this.model.takeExam();
}
});
```

As I understand, Model haven't some specific logic, it will only be simple object. Controller paste result of "render" function into element with id which equal to elementId. Render call when Controller is creating. I have read chapter about MVC form Addy Osmani's "Leraning JavaScript Patterns" but it's not much helped me. Do I need only create blank object with set properties in Model section ? How to properly create Controller ?

Answer (score 0):

if using visual studio right! click on the controller folder to add new controller where you can scaffold views if you want to
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwiNH.png

Check out his mvc training from microsoft it helped me understand MVC
https://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/en-US/training-courses/introduction-to-asp-net-mvc-8322